# C Code: Input struct data into a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a struct called firing solution which consists of the following items:

```
struct firing_solution_int {
    my_time time;
    int degree;
    double x;
    double y;
    //edit: fsnode next*;
};
```

NODE C FILE

```
struct node_int {
    void *data;
    node next;
}   node_int;

//Constructor' for node
void init_node(node *n,void *o)
{
    *n = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct node_int));
    (*n)->data = o;
    (*n)->next = NULL;
}
```

NODE HEADER FILE

```
struct node_int;
typedef struct node_int *node;
```

FIRING SOLUTION HEADER FILE

```
struct firing_solution_int;
typedef struct firing_solution_int *firing_solution;
```

Bearing in mind i have created my node file and have created the getters and setters for the firing solution struct and have set up the time.c file, I need to put this data into a linked list of which i can traverse and print out.

an example of what i will print out is:

```
Time 12:00 degree 45 at coords 45 by 150
Time 12:02 degree 47 at coords 48 by 140
```

What do i need to do to input the data? If more of my code is needed to help construct appropriate answers please let me know.

Comment: Well, you will need to define the node pointers pointing to the next node in your struct. (a `typedef` for `firing_solution_int` or forward declaration is required). (e.g. `typedef struct firing_solution_int fsnode;`, then at the bottom of your struct add `fsnode *next`). That allows a list to be created from your nodes. Then you will need to decide what type of list? Traditional `HEAD/TAIL` linked list, or `circular`? Then simply apply the normal `create`, `insert`, `print`, `delete` list functions to your nodes. There are many examples you can find.

Comment: The type GList from library GObject is what you're looking for. This implements a 2 way linked list with a void pointer for you to add your structure data. Get the help with it, the version of help I got when getting package gtk+3.0-dev this package contains the GObject libraries and headers.

Comment: have edited  to include first 2 lines of header, and is where ive put the fsnode next* line correct too? thanks for your reply think i understand how to do this now.

Comment: Is there a `typedef struct node *node;` that you're not showing?

Comment: there is lol, it's in the node header file. sorry mate!    
    struct node_int; 
    typedef struct node_int *node;